# How to open x-editable popup when hover?

Tags: javascript, hover, x-editable

Is there a way to open an x-editable popup when the mouse is on the text without clicking ?

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/63/

I can edit the names but I have to click on the link to do this. I would like the popup displaying when the mouse is over.

Something like: `<a href ="" onmouseover="openPopup()" onmouseout="closePopup()">abc</a>`

And, if this is possible, I would like that one specific popup appears when the mouse is over and another one when the user clicks on the link.

An example would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$("a").mouseover(function() {
//console.log($(this).html());
 $(this).click();   
});
```

or use toggle option

```
$('#users a').editable({
    type: 'text',
    name: 'username',
    url: '/post',
    title: 'Enter username',
    toggle:'mouseenter'
});
```

Comment: Thank's, the toggle option is perfect